# Defective components

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A manufacturer orders components from a certain supplier in batches of 20 items. Each batch may contain up to 5 defective components with the following probability distribution:
Suppose that 20% of all such batches contain no defective components, 40% contain one defective component, 17% contain two defective components, 10% contain three defective components, 8% contain four defective components, 5% contain five defective components.
(a) What is the probability that a batch contains no more that 3 defective components given that it contains at least one defective component?
(b) What is the number of components that are expected to be defective in a batch of 20 items ordered?
(c) Calculate the standard deviation of the number of defective components.

My idea was to use Bayes' theorem: $$P(A|X) = P(X|A) \dfrac{P(A)}{P(X)}$$

For instance, let event $A_m$ be "there are $m$ defective components in the batch" and let event $X_n$ be "$n$ of the selected components are defective".  Then we have the given marginal probabilities for $A_m$:

$$\begin{aligned}
P(A_0) &= 0.20 & P(A_1) &= 0.40 & P(A_2) &= 0.17 & P(A_3) &= 0.10 & P(A_4) &= 0.08 & P(A_5) &= 0.05
\end{aligned}$$

and the conditional probabilities for $X_n$ given $A_m$:

$$\begin{aligned}
P(X_0|A_0)  &  P(X_0|A_1) & P(X_0|A_2)  \\
P(X_1|A_0)  & P(X_1|A_1) & P(X_1|A_2)  \\
P(X_2|A_0)  & P(X_2|A_1)  & P(X_2|A_2)  
\end{aligned}$$

Similarly, I tried to use:

the event that there are 0 defective components $=β_0,$ then probability that the batch contains 0 defective components $=P(β_0)=0.20.$

the event that there are 1 defective components $=β_1,$ then probability that the batch contains 1 defective components $=P(β_1)=0.40.$

the event that there are 2 defective components $=β_2,$ then probability that the batch contains 2 defective components $=P(β_2)=0.17.$

the event that there are 3 defective components $=β_3,$ then probability that the batch contains 3 defective components $=P(β_3)=0.10.$

the event that there are 4 defective components $=β_4,$ then probability that the batch contains 4 defective components $=P(β_4)=0.08.$

the event that there are 5 defective components $=β_5,$ then probability that the batch contains 5 defective components $=P(β_5)=0.05.$

Then I cannot apply to my problem